Не могу рассчитать общую стоимость в документе в 1с
Имеется документ "РасходТопливо" с табличной частью "Расход".
В документе содержится такой реквизит как "ОбщаяСуммаРасхода", а в табличной части два реквизита:

КоличествоИзрасходованногоТоплива;

СтоимостьТоплива;


Нужно реализовать код, который будет рассчитывать "ОбщаяСуммаРасхода"
Процедура ОбщаяСуммаРасходаПриИзменении(Элемент)
    
        ОбщаяСумма = 0;
    
        Для Каждого Строка Из Расход Цикл   
            
        // Рассчитываем сумму расхода для текущей строки
        Сумма = Строка.КоличествоИзрасходованногоТоплива * Строка.СтоимостьТоплива;
        // Прибавляем сумму расхода к общей сумме
        ОбщаяСумма = ОбщаяСумма + Сумма;
    КонецЦикла;
    
    // Записываем общую сумму расхода в соответствующий реквизит
    ОбщаяСуммаРасхода = ОбщаяСумма;
    
    
КонецПроцедуры

Ошибка
{Документ.РасходТопливо.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(7,25)}: Переменная не определена (Расход)
        Для Каждого Строка Из <<?>>Расход Цикл    (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)

Как можно решить данную проблему?

&НаКлиенте
Процедура РасходКоличествоИзрасходованногоТопливаПриИзменении(Элемент)  
    ТЧ=Объект.Расход;
    Сумма=0;
    Для Каждого Стр Из ТЧ Цикл
        Сумма=Сумма + Стр.КоличествоИзрасходованногоТоплива*Стр.СтоимостьТоплива;
    КонецЦикла;
    Объект.ОбщаяСуммаРасхода = Сумма;
КонецПроцедуры

